# Could I get a breakdown of this sentence: 怎么会是在一所私校呢

Tags: translation, grammar, sentence-structure, ambiguity

Could I get a breakdown of this sentence: 怎么会是在一所私校呢
The translation says, "How is it in a private school?" But I'm not 100% sure it's correct.

Also, I realize 怎么会 is oftentimes collocated to mean "How could" or "how could it be that..."

But I'm curious if this sentence's structure is more like English and means something like, "How would it be in a private school?"

I'm just unsure and would LOVE an explanation!!!! <3

谢谢你们的帮助

Comment: What you understand is totally correct. As for break down: 怎么会/是/在一所私校/呢. 怎么会: how could. 是(verb): is. 在一所私校 is a prepositional phrase.

Comment: The translation "How is it in a private school?" is not correct. The Chinese sentence is a rhetorical question, or a question with high doubt. So how could it be in a private school is more appropriate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

怎么会： how come

怎么会是在一所私校呢？
How come it's in a private school？ (Dunno what "it" is without context.)

怎么会在一家私校发生？
How could that happen in a private school?

(strange: 发生：happen, 生发：grow hair)

Or maybe you had a “怎么回事”？

Comment: I agree that the sentence implies something has occurred in the school that surprises the speaker.